# Is there other characters that their techniques have a negative effect of using lifespan?

Tags: one-piece

In Enies Lobby Luffy used 2nd gear against Blueno and he knows that if he use that technique for a long time it can shorten his lifespan.

Is there other character and what is their techniques/abilities that they use that have a negative effect of shortening lifespan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the One Piece Fandom wiki, the [Ope Ope no Mi](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Ope_Ope_no_Mi) and the [Chiyu Chiyu no Mi](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chiyu_Chiyu_no_Mi) are the two Devil Fruits, "confirmed to shorten the user's lifespan if used in a particular way."

Interestingly enough, the exact phrasing on the [Gomu Gomu no Mi](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi/Gear_Second_Techniques) devil fruit page says that Gear Second, "hacks away at Luffy's life force dramatically, increasing a chance of having a much shorter lifespan because he is starving his body." So it isn't guaranteed per se that using this technique will shorten the user's lifespan, simply that it increases the chance that the user will have a shortened lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty extreme case would be the Ope Ope no Mi, technically speaking.

> It has the ability to give someone eternal youth in exchange for the users own life. Can't get any more life-shortening than that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, the healing ability of Ivankov's Horm-Horm fruit shortens the recipients life by a certain amount depending on the severity of the injuries. Luffy traded 10 years of his life to recover from being poisoned by Magellan in Impel down.